# Display image in a packagedapp/extension after selecting from Google Drive

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, picker

My packaged app gets images from google drive and then display them on the side. But I can't get the images to be displayed. I am trying to get the url of the image so that I can put that url in an image source. The image url that I am getting is actually an html page rather than jpeg, png etc. I have looked at the reference guide for google picker but nothing seems to work.

I am using this

```
    function pickerCallback(data) {
    if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {   
    var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
    fileName = data.docs[0].name;
    imgURL = data.docs[0].url;
    }
```

I want to use imgURL as the source for image selection but imgURL is not something like "https//:www.example.com/image.jpg. It is rather an html page I want something that ends with file type only then it will be able to display the image. Please let me know how can I get the image to be displayed in html page of my packaged app after selecting it from google drive.

Comment: Is the user logged into Google Drive?

Comment: Yeah, I get to see the list of images in google drive through my app, I can select the image but after selection it doesn't get displayed on the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch the metadata of the image, then use the `webContentLink` of the image, then the user can view it in a logged in browser. See the [documentation on downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads) for more information.

Comment: One thing I am wondering what is the Drive file instance?
  /**
 * Download a file's content.
 *
 * param {File} file Drive File instance.
 * param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
 */
function downloadFile(file, callback) {
  if (file.downloadUrl) {......

Is it this:
data.docs[0]? or  data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
from https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

I just don't know what arguments should I send when I call downloadfile function. Since fileId is data.docs[0].Id, therefore file instance will be just data.docs[0]?